# MVC4 Simple Membership When Does Automatic Login Occur?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I've got an application that's using the MVC4 Simple Membership provider.  I've added some code to the Login method that sets up some session information I need to deal with some security things.

If I close the browser and come back to it, MVC still shows me logged in in the top left corner and the User.Username properties are still filled out, but the extra stuff I put in there, obviously, isn't.

When or where does this "authentication" take place?  I tried checking the request and user objects in the Application_Start in Global.asax, but they're still null when that runs.

Is there somewhere else in that authentication pipeline that I can override or call my method to extract the things I need that would be more appropriate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Remember me" functionality has nothing to do with Simple Membership, or any membership.  And no actual "login" occurs when using it.  It's a persistent cookie that is placed on the users system, and that cookie is read when a page is loaded.  If it contains the correctly encrypted data, then the user is considered authenticated without having to go through Membership validation again.

What you need to do depends on how you are doing it.  If you're storing data in the session, this is bad regardless, because the session can be reset at any time, and session is not connected to authentication.  What you need to do, is check to see if the data you need is in the session, and if not, rebuild it.  This way it works when you come back later, or if your session is reset.

Session probably shouldn't be used anyways, because it doesn't scale well.  A better choice would be to hook into the OnAuthorization method of the Controller class and do what you need there, that way it's done on every page request regardless of what the session may or may not be.

Another option is to create a custom AuthorizationFilter.